# autocomplete doesn't working correctly after using patchForm

Tags: angular

I'm working on angular 8 project and I'm using mat autocomplete field and it's work but when I have to set default value to the field it will bring to me whole options without execute the autocomplete (for exemple I have to change Model field on updating model when I remove the default value and try to set new one it turn like a simple drop down list without autocomplete function).

My html code:

```
 <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="w-100-p" fxFlex="50">
                    <mat-label>{{'NAV.Category' | translate}}</mat-label>
                    <mat-error>{{'NAV.Alert_requared' | translate}}</mat-error>
                    <input
                    matInput
                    #typeInput
                    type="text"
                    aria-label="Category"
                    formControlName="Category"
                    required
                    [matAutocomplete]="auto"/>
                    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="optionSelected($event.option)">
                        <mat-option *ngFor="let cat of filteredOptions | async" [value]="cat">
                            {{cat}}
                        </mat-option>
                    </mat-autocomplete>
                    <button *ngIf="showAddButton && typeInput.value" matSuffix mat-button mat-icon-button (click)="addOption()"><mat-icon matTooltip='Add "{{typeInput.value}}"'>add</mat-icon></button>
                </mat-form-field>
                <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="w-100-p" fxFlex="50">
                    <mat-label>{{'NAV.Model' | translate}}</mat-label>
                    <mat-error>{{'NAV.Alert_requared' | translate}}</mat-error>
                    <input
                    matInput
                    #ModelInput
                    type="text"
                    aria-label="Model"
                    formControlName="Model"
                    required
                    [matAutocomplete]="auto1"/>
                    <mat-autocomplete #auto1="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="optionSelectedModel($event.option)">
                        <mat-option *ngFor="let model of filteredOptionsModel | async" [value]="model">
                            {{model}}
                        </mat-option>
                    </mat-autocomplete>
                    <button *ngIf="showAddButton1 && ModelInput.value" matSuffix mat-button mat-icon-button (click)="addOptionModel()"><mat-icon matTooltip='Add "{{ModelInput.value}}"'>add</mat-icon></button>
                </mat-form-field>
```

Patch data Function:

```
patchForm(object){
    this.profileForm = this.fb.group({
      Category: object[0]['Category'].NameCategory, //this is the autocomplete field
      Model: object[0]['Model'].NameModel, //and this one too
      Prix: object[0]['UnitPurchasePriceTTC'] || 0,
      vente: object[0]['UnitSellingPriceTTC'] || 0,
      Dimension: object[0]['Dimension'] || 0,
      TVA: object[0]['TVAInPercents'] || 0
    });
  }
```

Comment: Your `mat-autocomplete` does not call your function. Change `(optionSelected)="optionSelectedModel($event.option)` to your function name. Also, you don't want to regroup your controls by using the `FormBuilder`, instead use the `patchValue` function like this: `this.profileForm.patchValue({Category: object[0]['Category'].NameCategory, ...})`.

Comment: Thanks man the probelm is with `FormBuilder`